# Standard deviation for float array JuliaLang

Tags: floating-point, julia, standard-deviation

I'm trying to run std(list), where list is a Float array but I receive the next error:

"MethodError: objects of type Array{Float64,1} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array."

And when using []:

"ArgumentError: invalid index: 0.4"

Which is the first value of my array.

I'm guessing "std()" is not valid while using float arguments, anyway to make it work??

(Right now I'm using juliabox 0.6.2)

Comment: Maybe there is something in my code, I opened a new notebook, and copy-paste the lists, used "std()" and it worked. I was using the pkg "using Pyplot"... could that be an issue?

Comment: It seems that you created an array named `std` that shadows the function `std`.

Comment: Also note that if you migrated to Julia 1.0 you need to do `using Statistics` or `std` will not be available in default namespace.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me in JuliaBox 0.6.2:

```
VERSION
v"0.6.2"

A = [1 2 3 4 5]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5

s = std(A)
1.5811388300841898
```

As pointed out by Hckr in the comments, you may have shadowed `std` something like this:

```
std = [1 2 3 4 5]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5

std(std)
MethodError: objects of type Array{Int64,2} are not callable
Use square brackets [] for indexing an Array.
```

As pointed out by Bogumił Kamiński in the comments, in Julia 1.0.0 you need to do `using Statistics` to access the `std` function:

```
VERSION
v"1.0.0"

A = [1 2 3 4 5]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5

# Error here because using Statistics is needed in 1.0.0.
std(A)
UndefVarError: std not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at In[2]:1

using Statistics
std(A)
1.5811388300841898
```